# Hooking up a linked list at compile time

Tags: c, macros, code-generation, constants, compile-time

Consider a C struct that represents an entry in a singly linked list.  It contains a pointer to some arbitrary data, the size of that data, and a way to find the next Entry

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned char *data
  unsigned char dataSize
  unsigned char nextEntry
} Entry;
```

Next, consider the following collection of entries and the data that they represent:

```
unsigned char dataA[3];
unsigned char dataB[16];
unsigned char dataC[17];

Entry entryA = {dataA, sizeof(dataA), 3}; //It's important for "3" to match up with the index of entryB once it's put into MasterList below.
Entry entryB = {dataB, sizeof(dataB), 4}; //Likewise
Entry entryC = {dataC, sizeof(dataC), 0}; //0 terminates the linked list
Entry emptyEntry = {(void*)0, 0, 0};

Entry MasterList[8] = {
entryA,     //Index 0 - Contains dataA and points to Index 3 as the next Entry in a linked list
emptyEntry, //Index 1 - Unused (or used for something else)
emptyEntry, //Index 2 - Unused
entryB,     //Index 3 - Contains dataB and points to Index 5 as the next Entry in a linked list
entryC,     //Index 4 - Contains dataC and terminates the linked list
emptyEntry, //Index 5 - Unused
emptyEntry, //Index 6 - Unused
emptyEntry};//Index 7 - Unused
```

My Question:
Can you think of a way to figure out the value for "nextEntry" automatically at compile time?  Right now there's a huge potential for bugs if someone shuffles the order of the entries in the MasterList or adds some other data and offsets some of entries.  We catch all of the bugs with unit testing or integration testing, but it's inevitable that any change to the MasterList ends up getting checked in twice.  Once when someone edits it and a 2nd time to patch up the linked list indicies when the code fails testing.

My initial instinct is "no, that's idiotic" and "why would you even try this?" but I've seen some pretty impressive C-Macro wizardry in the past.  I also believe that any macro wizardry would be even worse to maintain than the above, but I figure it's worth a shot, right?

**Clarification** - I'm stuck with the MasterList array (and not a proper linked list) because the consumer of the information is expecting it to be this way.  In fact, there's other information in there that isn't part of the linked list that needs to be at a fixed index.  Then, on top of that, there's this linked list data.  The reason it's a linked list is to make it somewhat immune to getting shoved around as other elements with fixed indices are added.  For example, if it turned out that we needed to shove in a specific string at Index 3, entryB and entryC could get pushed out of the way, but could still be discovered by starting at the linked list head (fixed at Index 0) and walking the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there isn't really a good way to do this with the tools available to the compiler or the pre-processor.  I think the best way to do this is with a code generation tool that generate the array with the linked list already hooked up.

Answer (score 3):

By resetting and using the linenumber:

```
#line 0 
#define NUM ( __LINE__ -2)
Entry MasterList[8] =
{ {dataA, sizeof(dataA), NUM }
, {(void*)0, 0, NUM }
, {(void*)0, 0, NUM }
, {dataB, sizeof(dataB), NUM }
, {dataC, sizeof(dataC), NUM }
, {(void*)0, 0, NUM }
, {(void*)0, 0, NUM }
, {(void*)0, 0, NUM }
};
```

Output from gcc -E:

```
# 28 "index.c"
#pragma #line 0 __FILE__
# 1 "index.c"

Entry MasterList[8] =
{ {dataA, sizeof(dataA), ( 2 -2) }
, {(void*)0, 0, ( 3 -2) }
, {(void*)0, 0, ( 4 -2) }
, {dataB, sizeof(dataB), ( 5 -2) }
, {dataC, sizeof(dataC), ( 6 -2) }
, {(void*)0, 0, ( 7 -2) }
, {(void*)0, 0, ( 8 -2) }
, {(void*)0, 0, ( 9 -2) }
};
```

It should be possible to do it without resetting the linenumber.

Comment: Wow. That's really vile. Impressive, and I reckon I could use it, but I am throwing up in my mouth a little just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should just use an actual linked list instead of making the data of each node guess at the index of the last entry.

You were open-minded to preprocessor chicanery but you've created a design problem by giving runtime access to data that should be enforced compile-time where there shouldn't be one.  For one, each node has to have global knowledge of the array it doesn't even know it's in.  I know C doesn't have a lot of the magic of C++/Java/C# let alone Perl/Python/Ruby but this is just a data structure question not a language-feature question.

Edit from comment:

```
struct SpecialArray { 
    Entry* entries[10000]; //you'll have to write your own real memory management
    int lastIdx;
};

void addEntry(struct SpecialArray* arr, Entry* entry) {
    arr->entries[arr->lastIdx] = entry;
    entry->nextEntry = arr->lastIdx+1;
    lastIdx++;
}
```

Sounds like you'll actually need an Entry[] not *Entry[] from your comment but this can be accomplished by adding a deep copy function for Entry.  Then you can just pass `(&arr.entries)` whenever your client code expects an array of Entry.  The routine `addEntry` will manage the index issue for you and solve your original problem.

Comment: To Clarify, the MasterList has to be an array because the higher level consumer of the information contained in the MasterList is expecting to be able to access the information by Index.  There is onther information contained that isn't part of the linked list, and then there's this linked list embedded in there too.  I agree it's a mess, though.

Comment: Why does it need the field "nextEntry" then?  The owner of the array can figure that out since the owner of the array knows the indices, which the object doesn't.

Comment: Next solution up in complexity level is to write your own SpecialArray ADT that will have a push_back function that will automatically insert the correct index to an object with an "index" field in it.

Comment: I tried to clarify this in the original post.  The spec (that I don't control) requires certain items to be in certain places.  We can then optionally have stuff that's specific to this implementation in other certain places.  Finally, there's this linked list which is covered by the spec, but might get pushed around by the other stuff.  Since it's not at a fixed location and might get moved around as things are added or removed, it needs to be "Discoverable"  The linked list is the way that's accomplished

Comment: @djechlin: you must realise that tables like this occur often in embedded programming. In the ultimate case it even has to be solved by code generation. Index or pointer does not differ very much wrt initialisation: a pointer is basically &array[index], or just array+index.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do it with indices, it isn't worth the little possible gain. And don't use separate objects but initialize in place. Here is another toy example that even has the `next` pointer `const` qualified, so nobody can mess arround with it:

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct data data;

struct data {
  char const* D;
  size_t len;
  data*const next;
};

#define STR_INITIALIZER(STR) .D = STR, .len = (sizeof(STR) - 1)
#define DATA_INITIALIZER(NAME, STR, HERE) [HERE] = { STR_INITIALIZER(STR), &(NAME)[HERE+1], }

data table[] = {
  DATA_INITIALIZER(table, "something", 0),
  DATA_INITIALIZER(table, "something else", 1),
  { 0 }
};
```

This uses the C99 "designated initializer" feature, but you could probably come with a version that could do without.

If you really want all done by macros you then could use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) for unrolling, something like the following should work with `"p99_for.h"` (untested)

```
#define TABLE_ENTRIES(NAME, ...) P99_FOR(NAME, P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), P00_SEQ, DATA_INITIALIZER, __VA_ARGS__)

data table[] = {
  TABLE_ENTRIES(table, "something", "something else"),
  { 0 }
};
```